# Synchronise 2 local Folders through a Powershell button

Tags: powershell, user-interface, button, synchronization

I just want to make it clear, that i am completely new to powershell so sorry if i use wrong terms.

I want to make a GUI where you can write a source folder Path and a target folder path, with a synchronise Button. I've tried multiple solutions from the internet but i cant seem to make it work.

I want this all locally, so there is no server or anything involved.

´´´

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {



[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$progressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$lbl_Eingabe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$btn_ok = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$x = $textBox1.Text
$y = $textBox2.Text
$handler_lbl_Eingabe_Click= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here

}

$btn_ok_OnClick= 
{
Robocopy $x $y /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
$form1.Close()

}

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $form1.Close()

}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 321
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 626
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Primal Form"

$progressBar1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 161
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 201
$progressBar1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 352
$progressBar1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$progressBar1.TabIndex = 7

$form1.Controls.Add($progressBar1)

$label2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$label2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",15.75,0,3,1)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 191
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 32
$label2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label2.Name = "label2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 48
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 248
$label2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label2.TabIndex = 6
$label2.Text = "Ordner Synchronisieren"

$form1.Controls.Add($label2)

$textBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 161
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 134
$textBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$textBox2.Name = "textBox2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 352
$textBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$textBox2.TabIndex = 3


$form1.Controls.Add($textBox2)


$label1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 59
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 134
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Name = "label1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$label1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label1.TabIndex = 3
$label1.Text = "Zielverzeichnis:"

$form1.Controls.Add($label1)

$textBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 161
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 83
$textBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$textBox1.Multiline = $True
$textBox1.Name = "textBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 352
$textBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$textBox1.TabIndex = 3

$form1.Controls.Add($textBox1)



$lbl_Eingabe.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 83
$lbl_Eingabe.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$lbl_Eingabe.Name = "lbl_Eingabe"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 35
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 183
$lbl_Eingabe.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$lbl_Eingabe.TabIndex = 2
$lbl_Eingabe.Text = "Quellverzeichnis:"
$lbl_Eingabe.TextAlign = 32
$lbl_Eingabe.add_Click($handler_lbl_Eingabe_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($lbl_Eingabe)


$btn_ok.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 402
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 250
$btn_ok.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btn_ok.Name = "btn_ok"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 30
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 100
$btn_ok.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btn_ok.TabIndex = 1
$btn_ok.Text = "Synchronisieren"
$btn_ok.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btn_ok.add_Click($btn_ok_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btn_ok)


$btn_cancel.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 508
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 250
$btn_cancel.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btn_cancel.Name = "btn_cancel"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 30
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 86
$btn_cancel.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btn_cancel.TabIndex = 0
$btn_cancel.Text = "Abbrechen"
$btn_cancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btn_cancel.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($btn_cancel)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

´´´

I want it to show me the same files in the target folder as in the source folder, but just nothing happens and i dont have any idea why.

Answer (score 0):

$x and $y variables are not in the button scope

Try this

```
$btn_ok_OnClick= 
{
$x = $textBox1.Text
$y = $textBox2.Text

Robocopy $x $y /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
$form1.Close()

}
```